# Angular JS - sorting a collection using geolocation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, geolocation

I'm rendering a collection of store locations that contains coordinate data (longitude, latitude). I'd like to sort the results using the user's geolocation—specifically, ordering by closest store location. For context, the application is meant to make it easier for people to find an Apple Store (in Canada) with the iPhone they want:

http://www.applestoreinventory.com

I'm using the angularjs-geolocation wrapper (https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation) to get the visitor's lat/lng, but I'm not sure how to use the user's geolocation, once fetched,  along with Angular's orderBy directive to dynamically resort the collection. (I want to sort by closets proximity, something I'm comfortable with calculating in Javascript.) This is probably a simple question, but being new to Angular, I'm still trying to get my bearings. Here's the controller so far:

```
angular.module('InventoryApp')
  .controller('searchController', ['$scope', 'searchService', 'geolocation', function(scope, searchService, geolocation){

    scope.model_ids = model_ids;
    scope.store_ids = store_ids;
    scope.address = '';
    scope.find = '';
    scope.position = null;

    scope.refreshLocation = function () {
        geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){
          scope.coords = { lat:parseFloat(data.coords.latitude.toFixed(6)), lng:parseFloat(data.coords.longitude.toFixed(6)) };       
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.coords.lat, scope.coords.lng);
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    scope.address = results[0].formatted_address;
                } else {
                    scope.address = 'Address not found';
                }
            } else {
                scope.address = 'Geocoder failed due to: ' + status;
            }
            scope.$digest();
        });
        });
    };

        scope.search = function () {
          searchService.update().success(function (stores) {
            scope.stores = stores;
          });      
        };

        scope.refreshLocation();
    scope.search();

  }])

  .factory('searchService', ['$http', function(http){     
      return {
        update: function () {
          return http.get('/inventory');
        }
      }
  }])
```

So, any ideas on how to architect this within Angular JS?

Comment: You can calculate distance to each store and order them by distance.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. I know how to calculate distance, but in the context of an Angular controller, how does one do that? In Backbone it's straightforward—I would just create a computed property for proximity and then sort on that. In Angular JS, I just don't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is much difference for AngularJS. I have made an example. It uses Google places API for search. Map is needed (map = new google.maps.Map) because places API doesn't work without it. It will not work if your Geolocation is disabled. It uses Google map geometry API to calculate distance in meters and sorts stores with orderBy filter.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation/master/dist/angularjs-geolocation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry,places"></script>
        <style>
            .check-yes {
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>

        <div  ng-controller="searchController">
            Search for: <input type="text" ng-model="searchText"> <button ng-click="search()">Search</button>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="store in stores | orderBy:'distance'">
                    {{store.name}} ({{store.distance}} metres)
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('plunker', ['geolocation']);
            app.controller('searchController', ['$scope', 'searchService', 'geolocation', function(scope, searchService, geolocation){

                scope.address = '';
                scope.find = '';
                scope.position = null;
                scope.stores = [];
                scope.searchText = '';

                scope.refreshLocation = function () {
                    geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){
                        scope.coords = { lat:parseFloat(data.coords.latitude.toFixed(6)), lng:parseFloat(data.coords.longitude.toFixed(6)) };       
                        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.coords.lat, scope.coords.lng);
                        scope.position = latlng;
                        scope.search();
                        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                if (results[0]) {
                                    scope.address = results[0].formatted_address;
                                } else {
                                    scope.address = 'Address not found';
                                }
                            } else {
                                scope.address = 'Geocoder failed due to: ' + status;
                            }
                            scope.$digest();
                        });
                    });
                };

                scope.search = function () {
                    if (!scope.position) {
                        alert('Please share your location to search');   
                    }
                    searchService.update(setStores, scope.position, scope.searchText);      
                };

                var setStores = function (stores) {
                    scope.stores = stores;
                    calculateDistance();
                    scope.$apply();
                }

                var calculateDistance = function () {
                    for (var id in scope.stores) {
                        var store = scope.stores[id];
                        var storeLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(store.geometry.location.lat(), store.geometry.location.lng());
                        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(scope.position, storeLocation);
                        store.distance = parseInt(distance);
                    }
                }

                scope.refreshLocation();
            }]).factory('searchService', ['$http', function(http){     
                return {
                    update: function (callback, position, text) {
                        var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json';

                        var params = {
                            location: position,
                            radius: 2500,
                            types: ['store']
                        };

                        if (text) {
                            params['name'] = text;
                        }
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                            center: position,
                            zoom: 15
                        });

                        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                        service.nearbySearch(params, callback);
                    }
                }
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```